# How to pick AWS CIDR within the CIDR ranges of VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, subnet, amazon-vpc

When i try to add a new subnet in my VPC I get this message:

> `172.22.128.0/24` CIDR is not within the CIDR ranges of VPC.

My current VPC CIDR is `172.22.130.0/28`

Any help?

Comment: Hi, if the response below answered your question please upvote and accept it. That's the ServerFault way of saying *Thanks* for the time someone took to help you :)

Answer (score 13):

The best start is to refer to **[VPC and Subnet Basics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html)** which explains the VPC addressing and sizing reqirements.

Not sure if you are familiar with CIDR addressing? Essentially *the bigger* the number after `/` *the less* hosts and subnets you can fit inside such network.

For example:

- Your VPC CIDR is `172.22.130.0/28` where **`/28`** means that out of the **32 bits** in the IP address the first **28 bits** are the network address (that part has to be the *same for all resources* in your VPC) and only the **remaining 4 bits** (= 32 - 28) can be used to address your instances.

  That gives you at most **2<sup>4</sup> = 16** IP addresses in your subnet. With 5 IPs reserved by AWS you can only use **11 IP addresses**.
- Also because the minimum *subnet size* is `/28` you can really create only one subnet in your `/28` VPC and it has to have the same CIDR range, i.e. `172.22.130.0/28`.

  That effectively *prevents* you from placing your instances in *multiple availability zones* because subnets can not span across AZs.

**Much better practice** is to allocate rather large CIDR blocks for your VPC. *At least* `/24` but even larger if you can. Where *larger* means `/22` or `/20` or even `/16`. That will give you an opportunity to *create subnets in multiple availability zones* and create both *private and public (DMZ) subnets*.

In your case you can allocate `172.22.128.0/24` **to the VPC** and then create 4 subnets inside the VPC:

- Public A = `172.22.128.0/26` (in Availability zone **a**, e.g. *ap-southeast-2a*)
- Public B = `172.22.128.64/26` (in AZ **b**, e.g. *ap-southeast-2b*)
- Private A = `172.22.128.128/26` (in AZ **a** again)
- Private B = `172.22.128.192/26` (in AZ **b** again)

That will give you around 60 IP addresses in each subnet and you can have some hosts in *Private* subnets and some in *Public*, you can balance load across availability zones, etc.

If you want to go one step higher and allocate `172.22.128.0/22` to your VPC the addressing then would be like this:

- VPC CIDR = `172.22.128.0/22`
- Public A = `172.22.128.0/24`
- Public B = `172.22.129.0/24`
- Private A = `172.22.130.0/24`
- Private B = `172.22.131.0/24`

For the difference between **Public and Private subnets** refer to this answer: **[NAT gateway for ec2 instances](https://serverfault.com/questions/934948/nat-gateway-for-ec2-instances/934950#934950)**

Hope that helps :)

Comment: @omarjalloh I'm glad I could help :) If you're happy with the answer please upvote and accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The subnet you're trying to add is

1. not within your VPC's IP range
2. *bigger* than your VPC's IP range

As such, you can't add it.

<sup>Side note: I didn't know AWS would even *let* you make a /28 VPC. You'll only have fourteen usable IPs in there.</sup>

Comment: Ok,  any ideas what subnet range I can use?

Comment: @omarjalloh You should delete the VPC and start over. A `/28` is way too small for virtually any use case on AWS.

Comment: You can use /16 to /28 in AWS. A /28 is appropriate for a up to about 9 servers, which is a valid use case for some rare needs. Consider a single server that never needs to scale, has no ELB, etc, and your IP address range has to integrate with a large corporate range without NAT.